# What does the "mount" instruction mean in Rails routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mercury-editor

I cannot find the meaning of the keyword "mount" in [Rails routing system](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html).

---

I have set up [Mercury](http://jejacks0n.github.io/mercury/documentation/) to use within my Rails application. It added this line to my `routes.rb` config file:

```
Appname::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Mercury::Engine => '/'
```

**What does the `mount` keyword mean?**

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/mount

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Mount](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-mount) within the Rails routes does the equivalent of a Unix `mount`.
It actually tells the app that another application (usually a [Rack](http://rack.github.io/) application) exists on that location.

It is used mostly for Rails Engines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not know about Rails engines!

Answer (score 12):

Mounting an engine means that the functionality from that engine is available inside your application.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#mounting-the-engine