# Using devise in multiple engines and parent application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm looking to use devise in a parent application and its multiple engines.

The parent app is an admin application and there are 2 engine apps running in an isolated namespace.

I'd like to use devise in the engine apps with different routing.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: With Rack you can "mount" multiple apps within a single app. Make sure they share a database connection. See [what-does-the-mount-instruction-mean-in-rails-routing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144199/what-does-the-mount-instruction-mean-in-rails-routing). Or maybe check out the [devise-proxy](https://github.com/preston/devise-proxy) which I haven't tried.